# How do I get an image path?

Tags: java, image, file, user-interface, import

I want to get the image from my workspace, and to show it in a GUI.
So what I did was to place the image in the workspace:  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT3Sp.png)

And then, I did that:

```
        File coughfile = new File(cough.jpg);
```

But I get an error; cough can't be resolved to a type.
How do I import it?

Comment: You want a string.

Comment: @SLaks Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ImageIcon yourImage = new ImageIcon("C:/path/to/your/file/cough.jpg");

    JLabel yourLabel = new JLabel();
    yourLabel.setLocation(x,y);
    yourLabel.setSize(width, heigh);
    yourLabel.setIcon(yourImage);

    yourFrame.add(yourLabel);
```